# Flutter ios app is not running (Error (Xcode): Undefined symbols)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have been trying to run my app for a long time, and I have tried many things but I could not run it. I have tried to update some packages, run older versions of the app, update Flutter SDK, update Xcode, my MacOS but nothing really worked.

This is the error I am getting.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             56.5s
Running Xcode build...                                                 ⠉ 
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        25.3s
Xcode build done.                                           405.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbols:


Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.
```

this is the error with flutter run -v

```
[ +120 ms] Failed to build iOS app
[   +2 ms] Error (Xcode): Undefined symbols:
           
[   +2 ms] Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
           
[   +4 ms] Could not build the application for the simulator.
[        ] Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 378,969ms.
[   +3 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:752:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1350:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:348:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:294:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:112:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[   +7 ms] Running 1 shutdown hook
[  +10 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

I have also tried

```
flutter clean
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
pod repo update
pod deintegrate
pod update
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

I also ran flutter doctor and all seems good. I have even tried creating another project to test it and it worked without any issue.

But for this project, unfortunately, nothing worked for me. So does anyone know what might be the issue and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have pre-compiled Firebase libraries in your Podfile? (something like this: `pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.10.0'`)

If so, simply remove the two lines that contains those from your Podfile.

Source: I had the same issue as you after upgrading my dependencies and it took me half a day to find this fix.